# Tune Easton FMJ arrows for a 30# bow?

Tags: equipment, archery

I'd like to shoot the FMJ series of Easton because I really like how easy you can pull aluminium arrows out of the target in comparison to carbon ones. But the spine will only get as light as 500.

Is there any way to get them working with a bow weight of `30#@28,5"` by adjusting the point weight far enough up? If yes how much point weight would that need? The easton chart only shows up to 125gr point weight. It would fit with that according to the chart, but the chart is giving too hard spine values all the time.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the use of the Easton Carbon Ones, the shafts are excellent quality for the price and because they were originally only sold in spines for recurve or low poundage bows, there should be a spine that suits your needs, they can be also be pulled from the buttress with ease because Easton put a coating on them, the ease of removal the arrows from the target could also be improved by using Scorpian Venon or other arrow lubricant.